# XML node madness

Tags: c#, xml

I got about 1100 xml files that are read programmatically which works fine, except for one node in around 200 of those files. Redownloaded the data but still the same files aren't working. Maybe someone can help and spot the difference between the working and the non-working.
It's just a matter of one node (rest of that document works for all files) and its inner text.

Working node:

```
<sequence length="55" mass="6372" checksum="31681CC3DAC0C5D6" modified="2007-01-23" version="2">
MAKGIREKIKLVSSAGTGHFYTTTKNKRTKPEKLELKKFDPVVRQHVIYKEAKIK 
</sequence>
```

Not working node:

```
<sequence length="394" mass="43314" checksum="6EDA60255F43358F" modified="2007-01-23Z" version="2">
MSKEKFERTKPHVNVGTIGHVDHGKTTLTAAITTVLAKTYGGAARAFDQIDNAPEEKARGITINTSHVEYDTPTRHYAHVDCPGHAD    YVKNMITGAAQMDGAILVVAATDGPMPQTREHILLGRQVGVPYIIVFLNKCDMVDDEELLELVEMEVRELLSQYDFPGDDTPIVRGSALKALEGDAEWEAKILELAGFLDSYIPEPERAIDKPFLLPIEDVFSISGRGTVVTGRVERGIIKVGEEVEIVGIKETQKSTCTGVEMFRKLLDEGRAGENVGVLLRGIKREEIERGQVLAKPGTIKPHTKFESEVYILSKDEGGRHTPFFKGYRPQFYFRTTDVTGTIELPEGVEMVMPGDNIKMVVTLIHPIAMDDGLRFAIREGGRTVGAGVVAKVLS
</sequence>
```

Code that's reading creating the file:

```
XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
                        XMLdoc.LoadXml(Result);
                        XMLdoc.Save(Datapath);
```

Code that's reading the file:

```
XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
            XMLdoc.Load(Datapath);
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(XMLdoc.NameTable); 
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://uniprot.org/uniprot");
```

Just in case that might be the reason. XML code was verified as well-formed even with the different/broken node.

To make it relevant to others: What can happen in XML files that they won't get read anymore?

Comment: Your entire description of the problem consists of the two words "not working". That's not really helpful. What goes wrong exactly? Do you get an error? If so, in what function and what error is it?

Comment: There's no error. It's just empty. - Local shows "" instead of the inner text. If I try to read the attributes, it tells me, it's null.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's read fine? The simplest explanation would be your load code having a line length limit.

Comment: There's no problem with the length. I got XML files of the same type (they're created by uniprot - all the same) with an innertext of 1400 signs and it still gets read perfectly. I'm trying to spot that one difference in the 200 (of the 1100) nodes that pretend to be empty.

Comment: Are you parsing properties of the nodes? Because In the working node, you have modified="2007-01-23"w hich is a perfect datetime.
However in the not working node you have modified="2007-01-23Z"
which cannot be parsed as a valid date time by the same code that parses the above node.

Comment: Nah, can't be the problem. Checked another XML file with not working node for that - it doesn't have that. <sequence length="548" mass="57329" checksum="CD3A0FB505F74AD1" modified="2007-01-23" version="2"><sequence length="548" mass="57329" checksum="CD3A0FB505F74AD1" modified="2007-01-23" version="2">